# Symbols like _sqlite3_open not found error

Tags: c

Hi I am getting this eror:

```
Undefined symbols:
  "_sqlite3_open", referenced from:
      _main in ccRlWVer.o
  "_sqliite3_close", referenced from:
      _main in ccRlWVer.o
  "_sqlite3_exec", referenced from:
      _main in ccRlWVer.o
  "_sqlite3_errmsg", referenced from:
      _main in ccRlWVer.o
  "_sqlite3_close", referenced from:
      _main in ccRlWVer.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This is my code:

```
const char * filename = "database.db";
sqlite3 * ppDb;
int rc;
rc = sqlite3_open(filename, &ppDb);
if( rc ){
    fprintf(stderr, "Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(ppDb));
    sqlite3_close(ppDb);
    exit(1);
}

char * errMsg = 0;
sqlite3_exec(ppDb, sql ,display_result, 0, &errMsg);
if( rc!=SQLITE_OK ){
    fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", errMsg);
}


sqliite3_close(ppDb);
return 0;
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to pass the library you wish to link your code with, in this situation it's sqlite3.

If you are using gcc try adding the:

```
-lsqlite3
```

To your arguments you pass to gcc in your makefile/build command.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the compiler can't find the sqlite library. Be sure to pass the `-lsqlite3` flag when compiling (for gcc at least).

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not the problem, except the typo on the last line. The error you get, indicates that there is a problem when linking, specifically that the `sqlite3_*` symbols can't be resolved by the linker.

You probably need to specify the location of the sqlite library. If you expand your question with the commands you use for compiling, I can expand my answer =)